# Definition of "table variable" and "base table"

Tags: terminology, sql-standard

When reading SQL standard text (SQL:2003), I can not get the meaning of following sentence (in "Cluase 4.3 Tables" in SQL:2003-1):

> SQL-data consists entirely of table variables, called base tables.

I can not find the definition of "table variable" in the standard text, am I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

A table variable is an instance of a table. Tables are called *relations* in relational algebra - hence relational variable (or *relvar* for short).

Base table means that they are not views which are derived from base tables.